# Hadoop vs. NoSQL-Databases

Tags: hadoop, hbase, bigdata, nosql

As I am new to Big Data and the related technologies my question is, as the title implies:

**When would you use Hadoop and when would you use some kind of NoSQL-Databases to store and analyse massive amounts of data?**

I know that Hadoop is a Framework and that Hadoop and NoSQL differs. 
But you can save lots of data with Hadoop on HDFS and also with NoSQL-DBs like MongoDB, Neo4j...

So maybe the use of Hadoop or of a NoSQL-Database depends if you just want to analyse data or if you just want to store data? 
Or is it just that HDFS can save lets say RAW data and a NoSQL-DB is more structured (more structured than raw data and less structured than a RDBMS)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hadoop in an entire framework of which one of the components can be NOSQL.
Hadoop generally refers to cluster of systems working together to analyze data. You can take data from NOSQL and parallel process them using Hadoop.

HBase is a NOSQL that is part of Hadoop ecosystem. You can use other different NOSQL too.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is missleading you are comparing Hadoop, which is a framework, to a database ... 
Hadoop is containing a lot of features (including NoSQL database named HBase) in order to provide you a big data environment. If you're having a massive quantity of data you will probably use Hadoop (for the MapReduce functionalities or the datawarehouse capabilities) but it's not sure, depending on what you're processing and how you want to process it. If you're just storing a lot of data and don't need other feature (batch data processing or data transformations ...) a simple NoSQL database is enough.